# query related read write permissions

Tags: c, linux

I was reading about the creat system call in linux and learnt that we can set the permission mode. And that they can be ORed with other as well. But all of them were macros. Is there a way by which we can give permission bits directly without using the macros. Because learning every macro and its functionality is a very tedious job.

Comment: You do not have to learn all (any?) of them. Just have the knowledge they exist and then use the reference to look them up when required

Comment: You could use octal notation `0700` meaning `rwx` for the owner only. But then your code becomes less readable than by using macros. Macro names are for human readers! (the compiler don't even see them, since preprocessing happens just before lexical analysis)

Comment: I hate those letter-salad macros too. `S_IRWXG` indeed! Does anybody even know what the `S_I` stands for? Just use `0777` or `0666` (let the user choose with his umask which bits to turn off by default).

Comment: @heal I have the knowledge that they exist and use them also. But in my practical exam I don't think my invigilator is going to let me keep a reference book. So I just needed a simpler way to understand that.

Comment: @Rahul Chitta, well he should let you keep a reference book.  There is really no point to memorizing stuff like that.  There are enough actually difficult things about programming to test.  Over time you remember the common ones anyway because you use them enough.